# How to know the end of data import when using galaxybase-load to load maps in the graph database Galaxybase?

Tags: graph-databases

How to know the end of data import when using galaxybase-load to load maps in the graph database Galaxybase? Is there any other way than observing the printed information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 3 ways to know the end of data import when using galaxybase-load:

1. You can observe the print information, and the message "load successfully" indicates the end of data import.
2. You can check the graph status in the cluster management platform (51314 interface). If the status is "loading", it means that it has not ended yet. If the status is "ready", it means that the import has finished.
3. You can check the log file "logs/sys/sys.log". Information such as "load data end" and time spent will be printed when the import is finished.